# How to go to webpage without delay at "data;" page with Selenium Chromedriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am using Selenium and Chrome webdriver in Python, when I'm running script it opens chrome normally, but it waits in "data;" page around 10 seconds and than go to page normally. Can i skip that waiting time and go to page instantly?
There is my code:

```
class Instance():
    driver=None
    url=None

    def __init__(self, url):

        self.url=url

    def runInstance(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get(self.url)

instance = Instance("https://www.youtube.com/")
instance.runInstance()
```

Comment: Try updating your chromedriver to the latest.

Comment: updated chrome and chromedriver and still same :/